# Invite a friend invitation system error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to implement an invitation feature on my site. I am trying to display on each user's page  a list of the people they have invited. In my invitations controller I have the following code:

```
def index
    @invitation = Invitation.new
    @emails_for_invitations = Invitation.find_all_by_sender_id(current_user.id)
    @referred_users = User.where(:referer => current_user.id)
end
```

In my invitation view I have the following code:

```
<h1>Sent Invitations</h1>
    <ul>
    <%= for invitation in @emails_for_invitations do %>
      <li><%= invitation.recipient_email %></li>
    <% end %>
    </ul>
```

The output displayed on the site is as follows:

[image]

Why is the last line of the output occurring? I can't seem to get rid of it. There is nothing in my controller or view that is calling on this to happen. All I want to see is the list of emails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<% for invitation in @emails_for_invitations do %>
```

without the equals sign "=" will get rid of the output. The reason is you tell rails to render the return value of your `for` loop, which happens to be each individual invitation object as it looks ...